# CentOS 7 - Postfix to use highest TLS

Tags: linux, postfix

I'm setting up Postfix on a new CentOS 7 server. One thing I noticed after enabling additional debug that it tries to use the lowest TLS version when connecting instead of the highest. If I don't put in the last four lines in my main.cf file it will only use TLSv1 and not TLS1.2.

```
smtp_tls_security_level          = encrypt
smtpd_tls_loglevel               = 1
smtpd_use_tls                    = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file               = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file              = /etc/postfix/smtpd.crt
smtp_tls_loglevel                = 1
smtp_tls_CApath                  = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_CApath                 = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers      = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols  = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
smtpd_tls_protocols           = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
smtp_tls_protocols            = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
```

Using these settings I see this in the logs:

```
Trusted TLS connection established to hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.6.33]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher
```

Now my concern is whoever is still using TLS1 that emails won't be sent. Is there some parameter I am missing to use the highest TLS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Centos 7.5 and this doesn't happen with (stock) postfix 2.10.1-6.el7

Only difference in my main.cf from yours is:

```
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes

smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_protocols= !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
```

and I don't have any mandatory directives since I don't mandatory encrypt. You don't have my first and last line. I separate out general TLS, smtp and smtpd directives into different groups for clarity.

Logs show:

```
postfix/smtp[968]: Untrusted TLS connection established to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.102.54]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
```

I tried it with:

```
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

With the same results (TLSv1.2) so it seems to work for me out of the box. I would get rid of the !TLSv1 and add tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was this line that I was missing.

smtp_tls_ciphers = high